# Esiste il modo di dire "levarsi dalla mischia"?

Tags: meaning, idioms

Nel romanzo *Non so niente di te* di Paola Mastrocola, pubblicato da Einaudi, ho letto (il corsivo è mio):

> Anche quando ha ragione, anche quando basterebbe una frase per mettere tutti in riga, e lui, novantanove volte su cento ce l'avrebbe quella frase, eccome se ce l'avrebbe! Ma non la usa. Semplice, non la dice. Anzi, piú è convinto di aver ragione, di avere in tasca la risposta giusta, piú sta zitto. È come se dicesse: «Che bisogno c'è?» Quello è il suo motto, Jeremy glielo ha sentito dire cosí tante volte. «Che bisogno c'è?» Per Fil non c'è mai bisogno di fare niente. Lui preferisce *levarsi dalla mischia*, incamminarsi per certi suoi sentierini ombreggiati, per certi praticelli digradanti che si porta disegnati nella mente, sicuro che se li porta, Jeremy lo sa bene!

Siccome una ricerca su Google mi dà alcune occorrenze dell'espressione "levarsi dalla mischia" nelle quali il vocabolo "mischia" non sembra inteso in senso letterale, mi chiedo e vi chiedo: si tratta di un modo di dire? Penso che, dopo aver letto la definizione di "mischia" in alcuni dizionari, il significato l'abbia più o meno capito dal contesto. Tuttavia, mi piacerebbe leggere le vostre spiegazioni sul senso di questa espressione.

Comment: L'ultima parola si scrive con la *n*. Ah ops, no, scusate, altro modo di dire. :)

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: Ah, ah, ah! Ho letto molti libri di Camilleri, quindi ho capito!

Answer (score 3):

Si tratta di un uso particolare del verbo *levare*:

> rifl., **levarsi da un luogo**, **andar via**, spec. in frasi imperiose: *lèvati di qui*; *levatevi di torno*; *lèvati dai piedi* (pop. dagli stivali, ecc.). *([Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/levare/))*;
>
> rilf., **Togliersi da un luogo**, **andarsene**: *levarsi dal sole e mettersi all'ombra*
> || *Levati di mezzo, di torno, dai piedi!*, vattene!
> || fig. *Levarsi da un guaio*, liberarsene, uscirne. *([La Repubblica](http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/L/levare.php))*.

Qui, come hai ben intuito, il termine "mischia" è utilizzato nell'accezione di "moltitudine disordinata", "folla" (di pensieri), ed è scelto in maniera tale da comunicare l'idea di una condizione di caos imperante. Di seguito riporto il [significato](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/mischia/) letterale (1.a, 1.b) e quello figurato (2):

> 1 a. Ammassamento fitto e disordinato di persone che si azzuffano o di uomini armati in battaglia: *entrare, gettarsi, buttarsi, cacciarsi nella m.; uscire dalla m.; far m., provocare una m.* [...];
>
>  b. estens., ant. Moltitudine confusa di persone o di bestie;
>
>  2. Con sign. più recente, **mescolanza**.

In definitiva, "levarsi dalla mischia" ha il significato di "abbandonare una condizione pericolosa o caotica e mettersi al riparo", sempre in senso figurato.

Comment: Forse più direttamente l'analogia sottostante è quella tra scontro armato e litigio verbale, quindi il _levarsi dalla mischia_ da intendere come un non farsi coinvolgere in una discussione/litigio animato (pur avendo _la frase per mettere tutti in riga_, che segue la stessa analogia)

Comment: La voce **1** della [definizione di "mischia" del dizionario Garzanti](http://www.garzantilinguistica.it/ricerca/?q=mischia) sembra confermare quanto detto da @mario.

Answer (score 3):

Esiste "levarsi dalla mischia" come opposto di "buttarsi nella mischia",  il mettersi in gioco, entrare in relazione con altri, di cui il personaggio non sembra sentire il bisogno.

Answer (score 1):

Sì, il modo di dire esiste, ed è in uso.

Significa che, se sei in mezzo ad una folla di persone non proprio tranquille (mischia), te ne vai in un posto più tranquillo. Da ricordare infatti che "mischia" significa anche "scontro armato di più persone", quindi "levarsi", o "allontanarsi" dalla mischia vuol dire allontanarsi dai pericoli.

In alternativa, puoi dire "togliersi/trarsi d'impiccio", che è un po' più generico, e significa "togliersi/levarsi dai guai".

Answer (score 1):

Dico la mia,

> vi chiedo: si tratta di un modo di dire?

Non che io sappia (o almeno non l'ho mai sentito utilizzare con particolare frequenza da poterlo definire tale).

Non sono molto d'accordo con le altre interpretazioni, salvo che con quella di Erik vanDoren, che secondo me riassume bene il punto rilevante: "il personaggio non sente il bisogno di mettersi in gioco".

Per me il brano rilevante è questo:

> piú è convinto di aver ragione, di avere in tasca la risposta giusta, piú sta zitto. È come se dicesse: «Che bisogno c'è?»

Per me in questo contesto il levarsi dalla mischia corrisponde all'"evitare di pronunciare la propria opinione", o all'"evitare di prendere una posizione", per la consapevolezza (nella mente del personaggio) dell'inutilità del pronunciare la propria opinione o del prendere una posizione. Questo perché

> Lui preferisce levarsi dalla mischia, incamminarsi per certi suoi sentierini ombreggiati, per certi praticelli digradanti che si porta disegnati nella mente, sicuro che se li porta, Jeremy lo sa bene!

Ovvero nella mente del personaggio l'esprimere un opinione o il prendere una posizione sono cose totalmente irrilevanti, perché ciò a cui lui importa veramente è l'"incamminarsi per certi suoi sentierini ombreggiati [...]" e trarre le proprie conclusioni per se stesso.

Ovvero: al personaggio importa molto più delle sue personali riflessioni e conclusioni di quanto non gli importi di esprimerle agli altri.

Quindi, riassumendo, il "levarsi dalla mischia" per me qui corrisponde al "distinguersi dalla massa nel *non* esprimere un opinione o prendere una posizione" (che va implicitamente in contrapposizione a quello che "gli altri" fanno).

Answer (score 0):

Il significato più appropriato è quello di "estromettersi" (levarsi) dal contesto (mischia), per non venire interpellato da chi nel contesto è presente.

In altri termini, "non interessarsi della discussione, non partecipando" in questo caso.